# insert row in Azuresqldatabase by using Azure Logic Apps

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-logic-apps

I am having Azure SQL database and I want to perform Insert,Update,Delete Operations by using Logic Apps
and **is it  necessary to have a gateway** while Connecting to Azure SQL DB to Sqlserver Connector in Logic -app I have Three properties 1)Id 2)Name 3)Department in **Azure SqlDB**

```
**When HTTP Request is Received Code:**
{
"headers": {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
},
"properties": {
    "Department": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "Name": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "id": {
        "type": "integer"
    }
},
"type": "object"
```

}
[Http Request is Received](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsAYQ.jpg)

In sql Connector it showing Bad request:
[Insert -row Connector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnAd3.jpg)

The Body element of properties are null

```
{ "Department": null, "Name": null,  "id": null  }
```

The Output of Insert Row Connector
  {

```
"statusCode": 400,
"headers": {
    "Pragma": "no-cache",
    "x-ms-request-id": "3332d425-3e10-4f04-b618-63f359168acc",
    "Strict-Transport-Security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains",
    "X-Content-Type-Options": "nosniff",
    "X-Frame-Options": "DENY",
    "Timing-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "x-ms-apihub-cached-response": "false",
    "Cache-Control": "no-store, no-cache",
    "Date": "Mon, 04 May 2020 08:16:24 GMT",
    "Content-Length": "468",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Expires": "-1"
},
"body": {
    "status": 400,
    "message": "Microsoft SQL: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'id', table '.dbo.Details'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.\r\nclientRequestId: 3332d425-3e10-4f04-b618-63f359168acc",
    "error": {
        "message": "Microsoft SQL: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'id', table 'dbo.Details'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails."
    },
    "source": "sql-eus2.azconn-eus2.p.azurewebsites.net"
}
```

}

Note:I am not using any gate-way please guide me on the above task if you have any resource please let me 
know

Logic App-Defination:
[Designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1LH2.jpg)

previous error history:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhT2F.jpg):

data I am Passing in Payload schema:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gsDo.jpg)

Comment: What data are you passing to the http trigger?? To me the error message is pretty clear, you are trying to insert a null value in the column which does not allow nulls in it.

Comment: I am passing the data in payload schema in http request but still its showing null values in the body

Comment: data-gateway need to be connected ? while passing the data

Comment: For azure sql database, gateway is not needed. Please share following
1) Logic APP definition
2) Sample request that you sent
3) Run History from your logic app
The reason I ask, is that it seems to be straight forward what you are doing.
By the way you do not need to pass the header in the body of the trigger

Comment: I added three pics and the error data I already Submitted in the Code

Comment: Everything looks okay at surface, can you tell us how you are running the trigger? and what values are you passing to the logic app?

Comment: I am passing the values at http request which I shared in the above pic if you have any (resource or Examples) regarding insert a row by using Logic app to Azure sqldb

Comment: What you are doing is correct, are you using tool like POSTMAN or SOAPUI to trigger the logic app? You have not shared that detail with us? or are you running thevtrigger from the Azure Portal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is occurring because you are running the trigger from the azure portal. See when I run the trigger as shown in the image below,
[image: Triggering the HTTP Function from Azure portal> Error]
And I encounter following error
***"Microsoft SQL: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'id', table 'librarymanagement.dbo.DepartmentTable'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails."***

To properly invoke the HTTP trigger Logic APP, you need to make a HTTP API call to it. If you are just learning, you can use POSTMAN to make the call. Following are the steps you need to do

1. Copy the Logic APP url from the portal.
   [image: Copy HTTP URL]
2. Create a new request in postman and select POST method and paste the url copied in step 1. Also paste the body as shown.
   [image: Set Body]
3. Now move to Headers and Set the values as shown below.
   [image: Set Headers]
4. Click on Send

Comment: I tried with Post Man I got response status as 202 Accepted when I try to run my logic app "I see a same error id value cannot e null"